# subprocess.Popen; FileNotFoundError :[WinError 2]. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, subprocess

I am working on a script to analysis proteins. One of the def if for creating a makeblastdb, and then use it to carry out blast. The code is as below:

```
import subprocess
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Blast.Applications import NcbiblastnCommandline   
def blast_file(input_data_files, db_files, output):
        input_data_files = opts.input_file + '/protein_extracted_file.fa'
        db_files = opts.input_file +'/alleles_reference_db'
        cmd = ["makeblastdb", "-in", db_files, "-dbtype", "prot", "-parse_seqids", "-out", output + "/temporary_db",
               "-title", "temporary_db"]
        my_file = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
        my_file.wait()

    blasttn_cline = NcbiblastnCommandline(query=input_data_files, subject=db_files, evalue=0.001, outfmt=5,
                                          out=output + '/blast_output.xml')
    blasttn_cline()
```

The script works well until it get to the above def, and I get the error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
    **>  File "open.py", line 234, in <module>
    >     main()   File "open.py", line 229, in main
    >     blast_file(input_data_files, db_files, output)   File "open.py", line 165, in blast_file
    >     my_file = subprocess.Popen(cmd)   
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    >     restore_signals, start_new_session)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in
    > _execute_child
>     startupinfo) FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified**
```

How can I make this to work for python3? Originally the script was written in python2.7, and I have updated most of it but I am stuck in this area. Any suggestion to update it?

Comment: It's not finding the `makeblastdb` command.  Is that on your path?

Comment: @TimRoberts. , now I understand the error. I thought the problem was subprocess.popen. To work with makeblastd, I need to install blast, which is another problem when working with Pycharm.. I thought I could get away by installing Biopython. I will have to send a ticket to Pycharm to resolve the Blast issues.